# An error showing while run this prolog code

Tags: list, syntax, prolog, integer, factors

A syntax error is showing while running this prolog code for finding factors of a list of number

```
factors( N , Fs ) :-
  integer(N) ,
  N > 0 ,  
  setof( F , ( between(1,N,F) , N mod F =:= 0 ) , Fs )
  .
fact(List ,Result) :- 
    display( maplist(factors,[10 12 16],Result))
  .
```

Comment: You should consider improving your question. What exactly are you asking? What do you see? What do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a list in Prolog:

```
[10 12 16]
```

The correct way to write it is like this:

```
[10, 12, 16]
```

You need the commas between list elements.